# Regex: Differentiating underscore(_) and dash(-)

Tags: php, regex, validation

I want to construct a pattern that identifies the valid domain name. A valid domain name has alphanumeric characters and dashes in it. The only rule is that the name should not begin or end with a dash.

I have a regular expression for the validation as `^\w((\w|-)*\w)?$`

However the expression is validating the strings with underscores too (for ex.: cake_centre) which is wrong. Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how it can be corrected?

P.S.: I am using preg_match() function in PHP for checking the validation.

Comment: Solved already, an idea to use [`\b`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) for a shorter pattern: [`/^\b[a-z\d-]+\b$/i`](https://regex101.com/r/2OVSlz/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The metacharacter `\w` includes underscores, you can make a character class that will allow your listed requirements:

```
[a-zA-Z\d-]
```

or per your regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z\d]([a-zA-Z\d-]*[a-zA-Z\d])?$
```

(Also note the `-` position in the character class is important, a `-` at the start or end is the literal value. If you have it in the middle it can create a range. [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions))

Answer (score 0):

Underscores are being validated because they are part of the `\w` character class. If you want to exclude it, try:

```
/^[a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9\-]*[a-z0-9]+$/i
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the regexp with lookaround approach

```
 (?<!-)([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(?!-)

regexp pattern is created in 3 groups

First group ^(?<!-) is negetive look back to ensure that matched chars does not have dash before

Second group ([a-zA-Z0-9_]+) give matching characters

Third group (?!-) is negetive lookahead to ensure match is not ending with dash
```